# Why is my mesh refusing to snap to a specific object?

Tags: snapping

[image]

As you can see in the image, when I try to extrude the line of edges on the left, all of the edges except for the one piece (Why only that one?) snaps to the object on the bottom, instead of the nearest object.

[image]

Here is an image of my snap settings

Answer (score 0):

I selected to the object that I want to snap to, and applied scale and all transformations (ctrl A) Solved the issue.